# Specify index of array for Map operation

Tags: performance-tuning, map

I want to calculate the determinant along the last slice of a 3-dimensional array. So for I do this by slow the `Table` command. I know that for time reasons I should use `Map` or `Apply`, however couldn't successful solve the problem.

```
m = 2; n = 3; o = 10;
SeedRandom[0];
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n, o}];
Table[Sqrt[Det[x[[;;,;;,i]].Transpose[x[[;;,;;,i]]]]],{i,1,o}]
Map[Sqrt[Det[# . Transpose[#]]] &, {x}, {2}]
(*{1.04663,0.437045,0.479911,0.260814,0.205563,0.171896,1.20112,1.00502,0.855893,0.125758}*)
(*{{5.38795,4.19589}}*)
```

Comment: Using `TreeForm` might help with understanding the difference between the `Map[...,{2}]` and the transpose solution given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must rearrange the matrix so that the blocks you want the Det from, appear at level 1:

Consider the first block or matrix:

```
x[[All, All, 1]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

We can rearrange x so that these matrixes appear at level 1:

```
Transpose[x, {2, 3, 1}][[1]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

With this we can calculate the Det's using Map:

```
Map[Sqrt[Det[# . Transpose[#]]] &, Transpose[x, {2, 3, 1}], {1}]

(* {1.04663, 0.437045, 0.479911, 0.260814, 0.205563, 0.171896, 1.20112, \
1.00502, 0.855893, 0.125758} *)
```

Comment: ```Map``` is here only 3-4 times faster than ```Table``` (tested for 1 million samples). However transposing the whole array before we use ```Map``` or taking the ```Sqrt``` after ```Map```does not improve the speed. Is there a faster way to calculate this?

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

I was curious to see what the speed would be if one used the neural network framework to do the computation. It turns out that it is faster than using `Map` and the computation is particularly fast with a GPU. However, error accumulates with the number of components

The network will be made of a single function layer reproducing the code of @DanielHuber but within the framework of neural networks (without much of a network as there will not be any weights or complicated structure).

The tensor/array on which the function will operate has the same structure as in the question but with more components  :

```
m = 2; n = 3; o = 10^6;
  SeedRandom[0];
  x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n, o}];
```

The function using a neural network layer and higher order operator.

```
f = FunctionLayer[Sqrt@Det[# . Transpose[#]] &];
mapf = NetMapOperator[f];
```

Comparison between the two methods

```
mapf[Transpose[x, {2, 3, 1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Map[Sqrt[Det[# . Transpose[#]]] &, Transpose[x, {2, 3, 1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

`(* {0.22, Null} *)`

`(* {1.1, Null} *)`

Using a GPU (NVIDIA RTX 3050 Laptop) as the target device:

`(* {0.067, Null} *)`

However, the error between the two methods increases with the number of components on which `Map` operates (tensor length/dimension):

```
Table[m = 2; n = 3;
SeedRandom[0];
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n, o}];

{o, Max@
Abs[Map[Sqrt[Det[# . Transpose[#]]] &, Transpose[x, {2, 3, 1}]]/
   mapf[Transpose[x, {2, 3, 1}]] - 1]}, {o, 
Floor[10^(Subdivide[1, 6, 20])]}] // 
ListLogLogPlot[#, PlotRange -> All] &
```

**Maximum relative error (vertical axis) vs tensor dimension on which Map operates (horizontal axis)**

[image: error]

---

### Previous version

(still interesting for the syntax)

This is a natural task for [`ArrayReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReduce.html) introduced in 2020 (version 12.1). However, it is experimental and significantly slower than just using `Table` (for example using `Norm` with the example provided by OP `ArrayReduce` **was 16 times slower** than `Table`).

Thus using `ArrayReduce` at this moment is more for the convenience of writing code quickly than having high performance.

#### Discussion on how to use `ArrayReduce`

(code section below)

In the original `Table` version in the question, applying a function `h` to the two first levels of an array `Array[a, {2, 2, 3}]` would be:

```
Table[h@Array[a, {2, 2, 3}][[All, All, s]], {s, 3}]
```

To visualize the output of that code one can include a composition with `MatrixForm`:

**Note :** *This is only to visualize the output, using `MatrixForm` for purposes other than visualization, in particular within calculations, can lead to problems. One may search for such examples here on stack exchange*.

```
Table[h@MatrixForm@Array[a, {2, 2, 3}][[All, All, s]], {s, 3}]
```

Out: $$\left\{h\left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a(1,1,1) & a(1,2,1) \\
 a(2,1,1) & a(2,2,1) \\
\end{array}
\right)\right),h\left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a(1,1,2) & a(1,2,2) \\
 a(2,1,2) & a(2,2,2) \\
\end{array}
\right)\right),h\left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a(1,1,3) & a(1,2,3) \\
 a(2,1,3) & a(2,2,3) \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)\right\}$$

How can one do this, *functional style* ?

```
ArrayReduce[h@*MatrixForm, Array[a, {2, 2, 3}], {{1}, {2}}]
```

`ArrayReduce` computed the function `h` on the levels 1 and 2 where the input of the function `h` is a matrix made from these levels.

Why all those `{}` ? Why not just `{1,2}` instead of `{{1},{2}}` ?

Well, let's check

```
ArrayReduce[h@*MatrixForm, Array[a, {2, 2, 3}], {1, 2}]
```

$$\{h(\{a(1,1,1),a(1,2,1),a(2,1,1),a(2,2,1)\}),h(\{a(1,1,2),a(1,2,2),a(2,1,2),a(2,2,2)\}),h(\{a(1,1,3),a(1,2,3),a(2,1,3),a(2,2,3)\})\}$$

The output is the same as if we had kept the `{{1},{2}}` but we flattened the input matrix before feeding it to `h`.

Maybe it might be hard to figure out how this generalizes so let's add another dimension.

```
ArrayReduce[h@*MatrixForm, Array[a, {2, 2, 2, 2}], {1, 2, 3}]
```

$$\{h(\{a(1,1,1,1),a(1,1,2,1),a(1,2,1,1),a(1,2,2,1),a(2,1,1,1),a(2,1,2,1),a(2,2,1,1),a(2,2,2,1)\}),h(\{a(1,1,1,2),a(1,1,2,2),a(1,2,1,2),a(1,2,2,2),a(2,1,1,2),a(2,1,2,2),a(2,2,1,2),a(2,2,2,2)\})\}$$

Same ol' same ol'

take levels 1,2,3 -> flatten -> feed it to `h`

Ok,let's add some brackets

```
ArrayReduce[h@*MatrixForm, Array[a, {2, 2, 2, 2}], {{1}, {2}, {3}}]
```

$$\left\{h\left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{a(1,1,1,1),a(1,1,2,1)\} & \{a(1,2,1,1),a(1,2,2,1)\} \\
 \{a(2,1,1,1),a(2,1,2,1)\} & \{a(2,2,1,1),a(2,2,2,1)\} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right),h\left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{a(1,1,1,2),a(1,1,2,2)\} & \{a(1,2,1,2),a(1,2,2,2)\} \\
 \{a(2,1,1,2),a(2,1,2,2)\} & \{a(2,2,1,2),a(2,2,2,2)\} \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)\right\}$$

That might be hard to read. Without the `MatrixForm`

`(* {h[{{{a[1, 1, 1, 1], a[1, 1, 2, 1]}, {a[1, 2, 1, 1], a[1, 2, 2, 1]}}, {{a[2, 1, 1, 1], a[2, 1, 2, 1]}, {a[2, 2, 1, 1], a[2, 2, 2, 1]}}}], h[{{{a[1, 1, 1, 2], a[1, 1, 2, 2]}, {a[1, 2, 1, 2], a[1, 2, 2, 2]}}, {{a[2, 1, 1, 2], a[2, 1, 2, 2]}, {a[2, 2, 1, 2], a[2, 2, 2, 2]}}}]} *)`

Not much better if not worse but notice the `h[{{{` which means that `h` is fed a 3-tensor since there are 3 brackets. So with {{1},{2},{3}} `h` is fed the 3-tensor corresponding to the first three levels. Ok, last thing before we apply this to the question asked.

Given the discussion above what to expect from `ArrayReduce[h@*MatrixForm, Array[a, {2, 2, 2, 2}], {{1, 2}, {3}}]` ?
From the first example we see that {{something},{something}} means `h` is fed a 2-tensor or a matrix and {{something},{something},{something}} means it is fed a 3-tensor. So whatever happens, we know that `h` will be fed a matrix. Next we said that using `{1,2}` instead of `{{1},{2}}` means that levels 1 and 2 are flattened. So the result we find is :

```
ArrayReduce[h@*MatrixForm, Array[a, {2, 2, 2, 2}], {{1, 2}, {3}}]
```

$$\left\{h\left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a(1,1,1,1) & a(1,1,2,1) \\
 a(1,2,1,1) & a(1,2,2,1) \\
 a(2,1,1,1) & a(2,1,2,1) \\
 a(2,2,1,1) & a(2,2,2,1) \\
\end{array}
\right)\right),h\left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a(1,1,1,2) & a(1,1,2,2) \\
 a(1,2,1,2) & a(1,2,2,2) \\
 a(2,1,1,2) & a(2,1,2,2) \\
 a(2,2,1,2) & a(2,2,2,2) \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)\right\}$$

Ok, let's apply this to the original question.

#### Applying ArrayReduce to the question.

First, we might feel that all the brackets are tedious and we are not planning on flattening matrices anytime soon or at least not with `ArrayReduce`. So we can make a custom array reduce:

```
arrayreduce = ArrayReduce[#1, #2, List /@ #3] &
```

Now we can obtain the result by  OP:

```
arrayreduce[Sqrt@Det[# . Transpose@#] &, x, {1, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Out:  `(* {0.000292, {1.04663, 0.437045, 0.479911, 0.260814, 0.205563, 0.171896, 1.20112, 1.00502, 0.855893, 0.125758}} *)`

Verify that it worked:

```
Table[Sqrt[Det[x[[;; , ;; , i]] . Transpose[x[[;; , ;; , i]]]]],
{i, 1, o}] == arrayreduce[Sqrt@Det[# . Transpose@#] &,
 x,
{1, 2}]
```

Compare the timing:

`ArrayReduce`: $2.36\times 10^{-4} s$

`Table`:  $7.4\times 10^{-5} s$

Comment: For a speed comparison one should use many samples. For 1 million cases ```ArrayReduce``` has the same performance as ```Map```, i.e. about 3-4 times faster than ```Table```.

Comment: I just checked and for `m = 10^2; n = 10^2; o = 10^3;SeedRandom[0];
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n, o}];` comparing `Map`, `ArrayReduce` and `Table` with `RepeatedTiming`, I found that `ArrayReduce` was a little bit slower than `Table` and that `Map` was 1.4 times faster than `Table`.

Comment: I mean you should increase only ```o``` to 1 million and not change ```m``` and ```n```.

Comment: @granularbastard maybe Python would be faster not sure. If your computer has Python and Mathematica can find it, you can call numpy, which is a package of Python, from Mathematica. That said it might not be worth the trouble. I am not sure.

Comment: Depending on the version of Mathematica you have, you can write code from a different language by typing > at the beginning of a cell and choosing the language. This might require setting up the language before.